# Does shell (sh or csh) behave differently for handling arguments when commands get run locally(/bin/sh -c CMD) vs remotely (ssh node1 /bin/sh -c CMD)?

Tags: shell, ssh, csh

I am getting the following different behaviors for the commands when run locally vs that when run remotely via ssh.

```
$ /bin/csh -c \'/bin/echo a b c d\'
Unmatched '''.
$ ssh node1 /bin/csh -c \'/bin/echo a b c d\'
a b c d
```

Does ssh here is handling the command arguments differently and removing the escape chars somehow? (or the local shell itself is doing that?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Your example is failing because of local shell processing.

On Unix when process x (such as a shell) runs a different program y (usually as a child process, but not necessarily) it passes y's own name *plus* any arguments as a ***variable length array*** of strings, e.g. on an old system `echo a b c d` runs the `echo` program with the array of arguments (shown one per line for clarity)

```
echo
a
b
c
d
```

(On most shells on recent system `echo` is shell builtin and not a separate program, but *other* programs still work the traditional way.)

Because C-arrays start at subscript 0 and the argument array is conventionally named `argv` (argument vector -- C derived from BCPL where arrays were called vectors) C (and C++ etc) programmers often call the program name "argv-zero". Note that you can have the same program appear under multiple names in the filesystem, so its name isn't known at compile time, only when it is run; this trick used to be quite popular for things like `gzip/gunzip` but in recent decades it seems to have become unfashionable.

In shell input a backslashed singlequote means to treat that singlequote as ordinary data, not use it to quote other characters such as a space the delimits words and thus arguments, so

```
/bin/csh -c \'/bin/echo a b c d\'
```

runs `/bin/csh` with the following argv:

```
/bin/csh
-c
'/bin/echo
a
b
c
d'
```

csh (or a Bourne-type shell) takes *one* argument after `-c` as an entire command *line* (or script) to be parsed and the result (possibly) executed, but `'/bin/echo` is not a valid command line. Any remaining arguments are not considered as commands but as possible arguments *to* the command being run if it needs them.

The `ssh` client program on the other hand treats any and all 'data' arguments (not options and not the required [user@]remotehost argument) as forming the command to be run remotely, and sends them over the SSH protocol all concatenated into ***one line***, so your `ssh` command gets

```
ssh
node1
/bin/csh
-c
'/bin/echo
a
b
c
d'
```

but sends

```
/bin/csh -c '/bin/echo a b c d'
```

and `sshd` on the remote system passes that entire line as one argument, preceded by a separate `-c` argument, to your login shell, which then runs csh with

```
/bin/csh
-c
/bin/echo a b c d
```

so it takes the one argument after -c as a command line, which it can parse successfully and run.

And this combination is why we have dozens of Qs on several Stacks for many variations of "how can I get ssh to remotely run this command using special characters and/or interpolations correctly". While there is usually a possible answer, it is often easiest to punt either by running ssh with no remote command argument(s), so it remotely runs an interactive shell, and sending the desired command(s) as *input* to that shell; or, almost the same, putting the command(s) in a file, transferring that file to the remote system (or making it accessible via NFS or similar) and then telling the remote system to run the *file* as a script.